# indentation for method chaining

Tags: c++, indentation, method-chaining

Suppose I've a very long method chaining

```
object.SetA(123).SetB(234).SetC(345) ...
```

what's the best indentation? All compilers supports them?

```
object.
   SetA(123).
   SetB(234).
   SetC(345) ...
```

or

```
object
  .SetA(123)
  .SetB(234)
  .SetC(345) ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we're talking about method chaining on the same object (each function retuns `*this`), how about:

```
object.setA().setB().setC();
object.setD().setE().setF();
```

Long lines aren't just bad because your screen isn't wide enough to contain them. If that's all there was to it, just buy a bigger monitor or reduce the font size. They're bad because people *read* code one line at a time, and if you're doing too much in one line you break their tiny little carbon-based brains.

If all else fails, personally I'd indent it this way:

```
object
    .setA()
    .setB()
    ...
;
```

but I'd prefer:

```
object.setA();
object.setB();
...
```

Method chaining is a way to cram more onto a line, so if we're then going to split the lines back out again, I don't see the advantage. Sometimes we're forced because `object` is actually a temporary (result of a function call rather than a named variable) or something and we can't take a reference to it.

You could perhaps just let the line run off the right-hand side. It's annoying to have to scroll sideways or to have lines wrapping, but then again it's already annoying to have to do this in one statement, so clearly there's some incredibly important reason.

Comment: long lines are also bad because of source control

Comment: @tenfour: good point, you don't want to see a modified line in the `diff` and not be able to figure out where the change is because it's so long. Although I've just added some text arguing that if we're going to split into separate lines then we might as well split into separate statements if possible.

Comment: true but there are a lot of reasons why method chaining is used: in an `if`/`while`, function argument, or maybe the return value is a new object and your alternative doesn't work. Another example of the same concept is a long expression using operators (e.g. writing a debug log message using iostream operators). Even still, when the result is the same, why would you use a reference just to make each line a separate statement? I don't think devs get confused to see multi-line statements.

Comment: yes, an intermediate solution is the best: if I have 10 `set` method call I can use 2 lines with 5 methods each

Answer (score 11):

IMO, the **second** one is better. By starting a line with a ., it makes it explicit that it's a continuation of a chained call.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all compilers will support them. All you are doing is adding white space which is removed by the compiler during lexical analysis.

This is a question of personal preference but I would agree with the point made by Mike Kwan.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this if the chain is too long, and cannot come on a single line:

```
object.SetA(123)
      .SetB(234)
      .SetC(345)
      .SetD(345)
      .SetE(345)
      .SetF(345);
```

Otherwise I would go for this:

```
object.SetA(123).SetB(234).SetC(345).SetD(345).SetE(345).SetF(345);
```

Comment: vertically-aligning code like this is in the vast minority these days.

Answer (score 0):

C++ isn't whitespace sensitive, all of them would work on any C++ compilers (well... assuming they have no bug in the lexer). I prefer the last one anyway, with terminating semicolon placed on its own line (that makes adding more chain easier, a simple line copy would do it).